# split field in linux

Tags: linux, split

If there exists a column as shown below, lets say the column number is 5 in the file:

```
HSD,DFG
HUWE1
C16
OR5,OR53
SMS
SHOX 
SHOX
CRLF,GHJT,JGD
```

Could it be possible to print all the information into a new text file one string per line. Example output:

```
HSD
DFG
HUWE1
C16
OR5
OR53
SMS
SHOX 
SHOX
CRLF
GHJT
JGD
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question how this line splitting should behave *with respect to* the other columns. Should "DFG" end up in row 2, or should the field still be $'HSD\nDFG', but all in row 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just replace commas with new lines:

```
tr ',' '\n' <file
```

or

```
sed 's/,/\n/g' file
```

To redirect to a new file, just add `> new_file` ---> `sed 's/,/\n/g' file > new_file`, for example.